# storyboard graphics disappeared after upgrading Xcode4.x to Xcode5.0

Tags: iphone, storyboard, ios7, xcode5, ios6.1

Greetings for the Day Everyone!

I was working with Xcode 4.x till now. After official release of Xcode5.0, I upgraded my project built with Xcode4.x to Xcode5.0. Now I'm facing a weird issue. When I run my project in device/simulator with iOS7 it perfectly shows my app with graphics designed in xib. But when I run it with my iPod containing iOS6.0.1, it shows the app & those graphics which are created programatically. But not able to see the designs which are created using xib. I have tried so many solutions but none of those work for me.

1. I tried by editing Architectures and valid architectures from
   arm64,armv7,armv7s to armv6,armv7
2. I tried by removing armv7 from Architectures & valid architectures
3. I set a minimum iOS as deployment target
4. I did check very well with info.plist "Required Device Capabilities" as armv7

**Note**:

- this problem occurs for my every 
  **app which I have upgraded for
     Xcode5.0**
- I use storyboards

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time in resolving this issue. I finally found the solution.

Here it is, if anyone doesn't know.

For the graphics which are not visible to me in iOS6.x, if I have designed those via xib,
I adjust Autosizing for each control according to their place in the screen.

Thus, I got my designed back running successfully on device with iOS6.